# How to constrain method to return type where : Attribute

Tags: c#, generics, attributes

I have an attribute

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class]
public class ModuleValues : System.Attribute
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    public ModuleValues(string id)
    {
        Id = Guid.Parse(id);
    }
}
```

How can I create a generic method that returns the attribute once found?

```
public static T GetAttribute<T>(Type type) where T : Attribute
{
    object[] attrs = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(true);
    foreach (Attribute attr in attrs)
    {
        if (attr.GetType() == typeof (T))
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(attr.ToString());
            return attr as T;
        }
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

With the constraint in place, my method always returns null.

When I remove the constraint, I can find the attribute with a Console.WriteLine but cannot return it because the line `return attr as T;` gives compile error `The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint`

**Example usage from my console:**

```
Assembly x = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyBase));

Type[] types = x.GetTypes();
foreach (Type type in types)
{
    if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof (MyBase)))
    {
        ModuleValues s = CustomAttributeHelper.GetAttribute<ModuleValues>(type);
        Console.WriteLine("S" + s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just using `type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the problem:

```
object[] attrs = typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

You're calling `GetCustomAttributes` on `Type` - not on the type that you're actually interested in. You want:

```
object[] attrs = type.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

Or rather more simply, replace the rest of the method with:

```
return (T) type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), true).FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that that will also pick up attributes which are subclasses of `T`, but I'd expect that to be more useful anyway, in the rare cases where you're actually using inheritance on attributes.

Answer (score 2):

This should be:

```
object[] attrs = type.GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

Changing `typeof(T)` to input `type`. The `GetCustomAttributes` method gets attributes ON the called type.